# On OSX, how can I ensure that a command-line application shows up in the application switcher once it creates a window?

Tags: macos

I'm working on a cross-platform command-line application (in C++ on
Win/Linux and ObjC++ on OSX) which *sometimes* creates an OpenGL
context. The OpenGL context and window creation code is obviously
different for the different platforms, but on OSX it's done through
`NSOpenGLView` and `NSWindow`. There's no nib, and it's not built with
Xcode (it uses a cross-platform build script).

On OSX, the window is created and works fine, but the OpenGL window
doesn't show up in the Application Switcher (`Cmd-Tab`). This means
that it's tricky to find the window if you 'lose it' behind other
windows, and can often only be found by going to Mission
Control/Expose.

My question is: is there a programmatic way (i.e. a message to send to
the `NSWindow` object or `NSApplication`) to ensure that a (unix-style)
command line application will show up in the `Cmd-Tab` list once the
window is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform the process from an accessory to a regular app. Call `[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular]`.

Once you do that, though, the app will also have a menu bar when it's active. This is good because it's what users expect. However, you probably need to add appropriate items to the menus in that menu bar to get a decent user experience.

Your app will appear in the Dock as well as the Command-Tab application switcher. By default, an unbundled executable will get an icon that looks like a CRT display showing the word "exec". You can use `[NSApp setApplicationIconImage:someImage]` to set a better icon, although the Dock will revert to showing the generic executable icon briefly as the process exits.